# Can you get the full count of result even when using limit clause with Neo4j

Tags: neo4j

I'm limiting the number of results for performance reason, so I have a query like

> MATCH (a:Part) RETURN a limit 50

Is it possible to get the full count of node with label Part in order to display that the result represents 50 results out of X total records?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

But it will be more expensive and not that efficient as it has to load/pull all data.

You can either do (prob more efficient):

```
MATCH (a:Part) 
WITH count(*) as c
MATCH (a:Part)
RETURN c,a 
limit 50
```

or

```
MATCH (a:Part) 
WITH count(*) as c,collect(a)[0..50] as parts
UNWIND parts as a
RETURN c,a 
limit 50
```

Comment: Thanks Michael, will be careful not to use it too much but at least it answers my request (sorry for validating it 2 years later !)