# Neo4j Query set of node with 2 relationships and set value for each relationship node

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I've got this Query working:

```
MATCH (doc:Captions)-[:HAS_CATEGORY]-(c:Categories {id: 'ne0MtinOO6DXryRvqMxS'})
MATCH (doc:Captions)-[:HAS_PILLAR]-(p:Pillars {name: 'Feel Good'})
WITH count(doc) as docCount
MATCH (doc:Captions)-[:HAS_CATEGORY]-(c:Categories {id: 'ne0MtinOO6DXryRvqMxS'})
MATCH (doc:Captions)-[:HAS_PILLAR]-(p:Pillars {name: 'Feel Good'})
WITH docCount, doc Limit 12
RETURN doc, docCount
```

This will return a `docCount` of 25 and the `doc`s, limited to 12.
But it feels like I'm making the same call twice.

I'm wanting to not make the same call twice

Comment: You should modify the above to clearly state a question. You have only made statements.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29593998/can-you-get-the-full-count-of-result-even-when-using-limit-clause-with-neo4j)

I've updated it to look like this

```
MATCH (doc:Captions)
MATCH (p:Pillars {name: 'Feel Good'})
MATCH (doc)-[:HAS_PILLAR]-(p)
MATCH (c:Categories {id: 'ne0MtinOO6DXryRvqMxS'})
MATCH (doc)-[:HAS_CATEGORY]-(c)
WITH count(*) as docCount, collect(doc) as parts
UNWIND parts as a
RETURN docCount,a 
limit 12
```

I have Updated based off @cyberSam's comment

```js
const hasPillar = pageOptionsDto.pillar
  ? `(p:Pillars {id: '${pageOptionsDto.pillar}'})<-[:HAS_PILLAR]-`
  : '';
const hasCat = pageOptionsDto.category
  ? `-[:HAS_CATEGORY]->(c:Categories {id:'${pageOptionsDto.category}'})`
  : '';
const hasOrderBy = pageOptionsDto.orderBy
  ? `ORDER BY doc.${pageOptionsDto.order}, r.date`
  : 'ORDER BY r.date';
const res = await this.neo4jService.read(`
  MATCH ${hasPillar}(doc:${collection} {active: true})${hasCat}
  WITH count(*) as docCount, collect(doc) as docs
  UNWIND docs as doc
  OPTIONAL MATCH (u:Users {id: '${activeUserData.sub}'})<-[r:USED_BY]-(doc)
  OPTIONAL MATCH (c:Categories)<-[cr:HAS_CATEGORY]-(doc)
  OPTIONAL MATCH (doc)-[:HAS_PILLAR]->(p:Pillars)
  WITH docCount, doc, r, cr, c, p
  ${hasOrderBy}
  RETURN docCount, doc, COLLECT(r) as rs, COLLECT(c) as crs, COLLECT(p) as prs
  SKIP ${pageOptionsDto.skip} LIMIT ${pageOptionsDto.limit}
`);

return res;
```

Comment: You may want to replace all the `MATCH` clauses with `MATCH (:Pillars {name: 'Feel Good'})<-[:HAS_PILLAR]-(d:Captions)-[:HAS_CATEGORY]->(:Categories {id: 'ne0MtinOO6DXryRvqMxS'})` (the relationship directions are my assumptions), which may be faster. Use [PROFILE](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/planning-and-tuning/query-tuning/#how-do-i-profile-a-query) to evaluate your queries. Also, consider using [indexing](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/indexes-for-search-performance/) to speed up further.

Comment: Ahh, sweet thanks. I'll have a look at making this dynamic their could be a pillar or their could be a category

Answer (score 0):

A simple answer is to traverse the graph once and collect the nodes:

```
MATCH (doc:Captions)-[:HAS_CATEGORY]-(:Categories {id: 'ne0MtinOO6DXryRvqMxS'})
MATCH (doc:Captions)-[:HAS_PILLAR]-(p:Pillars {name: 'Feel Good'})
with collect(doc) as Docs
with [i in range(0,12) | Docs[i] ] as MyDocs, size(Docs) as docCount
unwind MyDocs as Doc
return Doc, docCount
```

This will return 12 lines. Each line is a node and the count of the docs.

Your comment above says the doc could have a pillar or a category. This query will only find docs that have *both*.

To avoid that, collect the docs from the first match statement, collect the docs from the second, and then join the lists before procedding.

The other option is to match on the docs first, then `optional match` the two possible paths.